# Exchange Management Tool Installation Error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, pssnapin

My goal is to create Email forwarding for 15k+ accounts in our Office365 by using powershell.

I may have to add that i don't have an education in this field and might describe things in a not very technical terms.

The problem i encountered is that i can not use cmdlets for set-mailbox, because i am missing a pssnapin. Using the commands for getting the snap-in into powershell i get the following error:

> Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.
>   At C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1:5 char:5
>   +     Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

I wanted then to install the Snapin by using Microsoft Exchange Management Tools. I enabled everything in programmme and features and tried to run the installation.

But then the following error occured:

> Summary: 3 item(s). 2 succeeded, 1 failed. Elapsed time: 00:00:18
>
> Configuring Prerequisites Completed
>
> Elapsed Time: 00:00:00
>
> Management Tools Prerequisites Failed
>
> Error: Active Directory does not exist or cannot be contacted. Click
>   here for help...
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=30939&l=en&v=ExBPA.14&id=51e5500d-8b18-4eee-bb8e-925d063b60a1
>
> Error: The user is not logged on to a Windows domain Click here for
>   help...
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms.exch.err.default(EXCHG.141).aspx?v=14.1.218.11&e=ms.exch.err.Ex28883C&l=0&cl=cp
>
> Elapsed Time: 00:00:17
>
> Languages Prerequisites Completed
>
> Elapsed Time: 00:00:01

Or is there a way to add the Snap-in in another way?

Best regards and many thanks.

Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your trying to modify Exchange 2007 Mailboxes then you don't need to use a Snapin this has been the case since Exchange 2010 where remote powershell was introduced in Exchange. If you want to modify Office365 mailbox follow the instruction in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984289(v=exchg.160).aspx the only requirement is the PC have powershell v.2 or greater.